# How to write query to avoid single reducer in select distinct and size collect_set hive queries?

Tags: hadoop, hive, query-optimization, cloudera, hiveql

How can I rewrite these queries to avoid a single reducer in the reduce phase? It takes forever and I lose the benefit of parallelism using it.

```
select id
, count(distinct locations) AS unique_locations
  from
  mytable
;
```

and

```
select id
, size(collect_set(locations)) AS unique_locations
  from
  mytable
;
```

Comment: The collect_set is the one which collects the things and removes duplicates. I can see that locations are from table, and to remove duplicates, you need entire table to be scanned. And its more of a aggregation I suppose. So can we perform the aggregation without reducer?

Comment: Definitely needs a reduce job,  just want to avoid the it needing a single reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two queries works for count(distinct var):

```
SELECT
 count(1)
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT locations as unique_locations 
 from my_table
 ) t;
```

Same goes for size collect_set I think:

```
SELECT
  size(unique_locations)
FROM (
 SELECT collect_set(locations) as unique_locations 
 from my_table
 ) t;
```